# Rails: Find the "has_one" record that doesn't have one

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, find, associations

So, I have an app with two models. Foo has_one Bar, Bar belongs_to Foo.

Now, to create a Foo you must to have to create a Bar to belong to it, but it looks like something slipped through the cracks because in my production app I now seem to have one Foo that somehow got created without a Bar, and it causes a 500 error.

Now, here's the problem:

I can search: `Bar.where(:foo=>nil)` just fine. But orphan bars aren't a problem, and this doesn't tell me what I need.

I need to find the one Foo where Bar is nil. But the database stores the relationship in the Bars table, ie, BarsTable has foo_id in it, there's nothing in the FoosTable to tell me it's missing a bar.

When I use `Foo.find(#).bar` I would get nil for the one bogus record, but I have a lot of records.

So, can anyone tell me how to construct a query that would return the one Foo that is missing it's Bar?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what the Ruby code would be, but I think the SQL should be something like:

SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT foo_id FROM Bar)

Comment: This worked! -- in Rails it's just `Foo.where("id NOT IN (SELECT foo_id FROM Bar)")` Thank you!

Comment: IMHO, the correct AR way to do this is: `Foo.joins(:bar)`, which results in a SQL query of `SELECT \`foos\`.* FROM \`foos\` INNER JOIN \`bars\` ON \`bars\`.\`foo_id\` = \`foos\`.\`id\``.  You can optimize this further: `Foo.includes(:bar).joins(:bar)` may save you a few subsequent requests to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Another way (without using SQL) would be to do something like:

Foo.all.select{ |f| !f.bar }

This would return an array of Foo objects which don't have a related Bar object.

In this method, you're not relying on specific table information. If the foreign_key column were to change in the future Foo -> Bar association, this method would continue to work.

Comment: This will be much less performant, as it will cause AR objects to be fetched and instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

For future user visitors another way to accomplish this is by doing -

```
Foo.all.where.not(id: Bar.pluck(:belongs_to_id))
```

This does two queries one for the pluck and one for the Foo.where.not(id: plucked_ids).

Answer (score 0):

Use left_outer_join for this.

```
Foo.left_outer_joins(:bar).where(bars: { id: nil })
```

Rails added a nice convenience method for this situation

```
Foo.where.missing(:bar)
```